# Evaluate function with two arguments in foreach loop in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to call a function with two parameters inside a foreach loop

```
define obj-goal
$1: $2
    gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@
endef
```

Two arguments for the function are coming from two lists

```
C_FILES:=$(patsubst %.py,%.c,$(SRC_FILES))
OBJ_FILES:=$(patsubst %.py,build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
```

Currently what I did was concatenate the two variables and then split again using two functions `first-var` and `last-var` then passed into the required function

```
first-var = $(firstword $(subst ^, ,$1))
last-var = $(lastword $(subst ^, ,$1))

OC_FLIST:=$(join $(OBJ_FILES),$(patsubst %,^%,$(C_FILES)))
$(foreach filecat,$(OC_FLIST),$(info $(call obj-goal,$(call first-var,$(filecat)),$(call last-var,$(filecat)))))
```

Is there a better way to do this? like:

```
$(foreach (ofile, cfile), ($(OBJ_FILES), $(C_FILES)) ,$(eval $(call obj-goal,$(ofile),$(cfile))))
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932205/parallel-iteration-over-lists-in-makefile-or-cmake-file/60203826#60203826)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way. Use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(OBJ_FILES): build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, Beta's answer is way better.

The general question of iterating/zipping two lists needs indexing, and, I'm afraid, `$(shell seq)`:

```
LIST1 := a b c
LIST2 := 1 2 3

test:
    echo $(foreach INDEX, \
                   $(shell seq 1 $(words $(LIST1))), \
                   $(word $(INDEX), $(LIST1)) and $(word $(INDEX), $(LIST2)))
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this will be helpful in other situations. for this eg: `$(foreach INDEX, $(shell seq 1 $(words $(LIST1))), $(info $(call obj-goal, $(word $(INDEX), $(LIST1)), $(word $(INDEX), $(LIST2)))))`

Comment: `$(call)` is a code smell in makefile. If you're making callable macros, then you should be doing something else.

Comment: Sorry, but your last comment is ill-advised. Complexity dosn't go away just by distributing it over several tools or languages, quite the contrary.

Comment: I didn't say it needs to be moved into another language. To be more specific, most times the proper tool for the job is a pattern rule instead of a macro. Macros are harder to debug, they are executed each time any target is run, and `make`'s macro language is poor; its primary language is target rules.